# Codeigniter - Facing issue sending email and input of user email

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email

i make simple form user submit email and city submit the form and send email to user of thanks i host website on godaddy, when i submit it shows errors.
1- Sending email error
2- $email input not get 
for suggestion i share code.

**user.php controller**

```
public function sendUserMail($email) {
   $this->load->library('email');
   $email = $this->input->get("email");   
   $this->email->from('noreply@abc.com', 'Halalat');
   $this->email->to('$email'); 
   $this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
   $this->email->message('Testing');   
   //$this->email->attach('/assests/images/photo1.jpg');
   $this->email->send();
   echo $this->email->print_debugger();
  }
```

**In config folder i make email.php**

```
<?php

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'host.abc.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'noreply@abc.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'abc';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

?>
```

**user_model.php in model**

```
function create_member()
 {
   $new_member_insert_data = array(
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'city' => $this->input->post('city'),       
   );
   $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data); 
  return $insert;


 } //create_member
```

Comment: Please post also error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
   $this->load->library('email');
   $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
   $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://host.abc.com';
   $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
   $config['smtp_user'] = 'noreply@abc.com';
   $config['smtp_pass'] = 'abc';
   $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
   $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
   $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
   $this->email->initialize($config);
   $email = $this->input->get("email");   
   $this->email->from('noreply@abc.com', 'Halalat');
   $this->email->to('$email'); 
   $this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
   $this->email->message('Testing');   
   if(!$this->email->send()){
     echo $this->email->print_debugger();
   }
```

Comment: i already do $email but this variable not work and facing error if you need i will share all of codes

Comment: Are you sure the host and port are correct? What does the error report say?

Comment: check error_log file first then share your error!